# How to convert yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss to yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ?

Tags: php, date, datetime, utc

I need to send the datetime to an API.

I am trying to do like this, but it isn't working.

```
$startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('yyyy-MM-dd\THH:mm:ssZ', '2014-06-13 14:30:00');
```

Unfortunately I get `2014-06-13T13:30:00.000Z` whereas I need it to be in this format: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`

I'm not sure where I am going wrong. Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to convert and read in the date at the same time which is not how `DateTime::createFromFormat()` works. In fact, you don't need that method at all since your starting date format is supported by DateTime.

Just pass the date as a parameter to `DateTime()` and then format it accordingly. (As noted in the comments, make sure your date is in UTC).

```
echo (new DateTime('2014-06-13 14:30:00'))->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
```

Comment: @JognConde I tried that and I get`2014-06-13T14:30:00+02:00`. I'm still unsure how to get the specified format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`

Comment: The result is now `2014-06-13T14:30:007200` Any more ideas?

Comment: `->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');`. But be sure, that your input time is in Zulu timezone (UTC).

Comment: Thank you guys for your help! I spent far too long trying to figure this out